# webpack-dev-server doesn't compile React components in subfolders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, mobx

I'm developing React + Mobx application using webpack-dev-server.

Project folders structure:

```
/assets
/dist
/public
/src
  /components
    /common
      Field.jsx
      Button.jsx
      ...
    ComponentA.jsx
    ComponentB.jxs
    ...
  /stores
    StoreA.js
    StoreB.js
    ...
  index.jsx
  ...
package.json
webpack.config.js
...
```

When i start dev server and change some files in components or stores folders (ComponentA.jsx or StoreA.js for example) all changes will be applied and react application will be redrawn in browser.

But when i'm changing files from components subfolders (/common/Field.jsx for example) webpack-dev-server not see that changes and application is not redrawn. Also if i made some changes in components folder application will be redrawn, but changes in components/common files will not be applied until webpack-dev-server reload.

webpack.config file:

```
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '[name]-[hash].css',
  allChunks: true
});

const ROOT_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname);
const SRC_PATH = path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'src', 'index.jsx');
const LOGIN_PATH = path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'src', 'login.jsx');
const DIST_PATH = path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'dist');

const babel = {
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {
    presets: [ 'react', 'es2015', 'stage-0' ],
    plugins: [
      [
        "transform-runtime", {
          "polyfill": false,
          "regenerator": true
        }
      ],
      'transform-decorators-legacy'
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = (env) => ({
  entry: (env.test ? ['babel-polyfill', 'whatwg-fetch'] : {
    index: ['babel-polyfill', 'whatwg-fetch', SRC_PATH],
    login: ['babel-polyfill', 'whatwg-fetch', LOGIN_PATH]
  }),
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: '3000'
  },
  output: {
    path: DIST_PATH,
    filename: env.production ? "bundle-[name]-[hash].js" : "bundle-[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: (env.test ? [ babel ] : [ babel, 'eslint-loader' ])
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: extractCSS.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader'])
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|ico|svg|json)$/,
        loader: env.production ?
          'file-loader?name=img/[name]-[hash].[ext]' :
          'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractCSS,
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.ejs',
      filename: 'index.html',
      sha: childProcess.execSync('git rev-parse HEAD').toString().replace(/\n/g, ''),
      env,
      chunks: ['index']
    }),
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/login.ejs',
      filename: 'login.html',
      sha: childProcess.execSync('git rev-parse HEAD').toString().replace(/\n/g, ''),
      env,
      chunks: ['login']
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx' ],
    modules: ['node_modules', 'assets', 'src']
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  }
});
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have tried adding

```
watchOptions: {
  poll: true
}
```

in webpack configuration?

Comment: Thanks! You're really saved my day!